# Basis-dependent results on matrices

Tags: matrices, big-list

It is common fashion to try to formulate results about matrices in a basis-free way, using linear algebra. What are some good examples of situations where this is impossible? I illustrate what I have in mind with the following two examples:

1. The [Perron-Frobenius theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem). Here the nonnegativity is essential, and the conclusions are substantial.
2. [Stochastic matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix), in general. Here again, the crucial thing is nonnegativity.

Are there other such situations where going basis-free is an impossible task? The examples I gave utilize nonnegativity of entries; if there are examples utilizing some other fact, that will be particularly nice.

Comment: I don't get exactly what basis-free means. For example, is matrix diagonalization $A = S^{-1}\Lambda S$ basis-free?